# recursive file search, C , linux

Tags: c, recursion, file, search

hi guys this script recursively searches for files with a certain extension and possibly in a directory passed by the terminal ....(In case no directory has been passed, search from the current one) I believe it works correctly but I wanted to ask you if you noticed any flaws and report them to me or just tell me that everything is ok ...thanksss

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<sys/stat.h>
 #include<errno.h>
 #include<stdlib.h> 
 #include<dirent.h>    
 #include<stdarg.h>
 #include<limits.h>
 #include<string.h>
 #include<time.h>



 char * scrivi(const char * a, char * B) {

 char *targetdir = malloc(2048);
 strcpy(targetdir,a);
 strcat(targetdir,"/");
 strcat(targetdir,B);
 return targetdir;
 } 



 void ricor1(const char estensione[],const char nomedirectory[]){

 struct stat attr;
 char dbuf[PATH_MAX+1];
 DIR * fh ;
 struct dirent *fdata;
 struct stat buf;

 if((fh=opendir(nomedirectory))==NULL){
 perror("ERRORE 1");
 exit(errno);
 }


 while((fdata = readdir (fh))!=NULL){
 if(strcmp(fdata->d_name,".")==0){
 continue;
 }

 if(strcmp(fdata->d_name,"..")==0){
 continue;
  }


 char *percorso;
 percorso = scrivi(nomedirectory,fdata->d_name);
 if (fdata->d_type==DT_DIR){

 ricor1(estensione,percorso);
  }
 if (fdata->d_type == DT_REG && strstr(fdata->d_name, estensione)) {

realpath(percorso, dbuf);
printf("[%s]", dbuf);

stat(percorso, &attr);

printf("%s\n", ctime(&attr.st_mtime));

 }

free(percorso);
 }
closedir(fh);
 } 


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {



if(argc==3){

printf("Checking existence directory.. \n");

DIR* dir=opendir(argv[2]);

if(dir){    
closedir(dir);        
ricor1(argv[1],argv[2]);

 } 

else if (ENOENT==errno){

printf("Directory doesn't exist\n");
  }

else{

printf("error"); 

     }   
 }


else if(argc==2){



ricor1(argv[1],"./");

  }
 }
```

Comment: _"I believe it works correctly"_ What do you mean? Didn't you test your code?

Comment: it works, I wanted to know if there could be any errors that I had not considered ...

Comment: At least you should indent your code correctly to enhance readability.

Comment: Please keep in mind that the C programming language is not a scripting language, it is a compiled language, scripts run through an interpreter, compilers generate an executable file that can be run more quickly and efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

> ... if you noticed any flaws ....

Problems with `scrivi()`

```
char * scrivi(const char * a, char * B) {

 char *targetdir = malloc(2048);
 strcpy(targetdir,a);
 strcat(targetdir,"/");
 strcat(targetdir,B);
 return targetdir;
 }
```

**Magic number**

Why 2048?  Big enough - who knows?  Makes more sense to find the size needed and allocate rather than risk *undefined behavior* of a buffer overflow with `strcpy(targetdir,a);`

**`strcpy(), strcat(), strcat()`**

Walking down the string 3 times.  Bad enough to do twice.   (With a larger code re-write, we could avoid all repetitive walks down `a`, that is far below.)

**`char * B` better as `const char * b`**

Use `const`.

**No error checking**

With a recursion function, out-of-memory is a concern.

**Alternative**

```
char * scrivi(const char *a, const char *b) {
  size_t a_len = strlen(a);    
  size_t b_len = strlen(b);    
  char *targetdir = malloc(a_len + 1 + b_len + 1);

  if (targetdir) {
    memcpy(targetdir, a, a_len);
    targetdir[a_len] = '/';
    memcpy(targetdir + a_len + 1, b, b_len + 1);
  }
  return targetdir;
}
```

---

**Re-write trick**

Rather than repetitive `malloc()/free()`, allocate **once** ever for a working file path buffer.

```
size_t file_path_size = PATH_MAX * 2;  // Let us be generous.
char file_path = mallloc(file_path_size);
```

Before code calls `ricor1()` the first time, fill in the directory path and pass how much used, how much total.

```
strcpy(file_path, argv[2]);
ricor1(argv[1], file_path, strlen(argv[2]), file_path_size);
```

When forming the the full path, rather than `percorso = scrivi(nomedirectory, fdata->d_name);` with its allocations, write at the right place.

```
int length = snprintf(file_path + used, file_path_size - used, "/%s", fdata->d_name);
```

When recursing, append the sub-directory name and re-curse with an updated length

```
ricor1(estensione, file_path, used + length, file_path_size);
```

Include ample size error checking.

Consider code only ever needs   1 `file_path[]` at a time.

Comment: `stpcpy` also works.

Comment: @S.S.Anne Yes - could use that approach.  Yet a crucial attribute of forming the file path in a _recursive_ function is 1) never overwriting the buffer and 2) detecting when the buffer was insufficient.  I find `snprintf()` useful in insuring #1 and useful to detecting #2 and more convenient  than the `strcpy()` route.  I also find compilers more often these days emit efficient code with `*printf()` and friends due to analyzability and so less concern about a tedious format string interpretation that is no longer there.  IAC, it is big O that I watch.

Comment: No, `st` **p** `cpy`. There's also `stpncpy`.

Comment: @S.S.Anne Aha, Yes.  could use `stpcpy()` to remove the [painter problem](https://wiki.c2.com/?ShlemielThePainter), That like `strcpy()`, `strcat()` still obliges other code to avoid buffer overflow and insufficient size detection.  I'll look more into `stpncpy()`.  They also has the short-coming of not existing in the standard C library - but of course neither does `opendir()` and friends.